# Swift UIView's sizeToFit() always returning 0 in height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am trying to create a ViewBuilder class that sets up views and returns them to the caller. The caller then only has to constraint one view that holds some subviews which are constraint inside the view. That way, I'd like to save some code.

Things will get more clear with the code:

**Code inside my Collection-View-Cell:**

```
let postView = ViewComponentsBuilder.generatePostView(postItem: contentInteraction!.nativeContent as! Post)
postView.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.contentView.addSubview(postView)
postView.anchor(top: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, left: self.contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.contentView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 16, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 16, width: 0, height: 0)
postView.layoutSubviews()

postView.sizeToFit()
print(postView.frame.height) // always prints 0
```

**Code in the ViewBuilder Class:**

```
static func generatePostView(postItem: Post) -> UIView {

        let postDescription: DefaultLabel = {
            let lbl = DefaultLabel(labelFont: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Medium", size: 16)!, labelTextColor: .black, labelText: "")
            lbl.numberOfLines = 0
            lbl.text = postItem.content.message
            lbl.layer.borderWidth = 1
            return lbl
        }()

        let postView = UIView()

        postView.addSubview(postDescription)
        postDescription.anchor(top: postView.topAnchor, left: postView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: postView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        postDescription.sizeToFit()

        postView.layoutSubviews()

        return postView
    }
```

**This is the behavior I get:**
[image: Bricked view constraints]

As you can see, the postView, generated from the ViewComponentsBuilder does not enclose its subviews (in this case it's a label containing the post description; **the border you see is not from the postView but from the label correctly resizing its height according to the content**). This behavior causes the entire view to brick.

I really don't know where the problem is and would be incredibly thankful for some advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you implemented `sizeThatFits:` in `DefaultLabel`?

Comment: No. But the label itself has the correct sizeToFit behavior?

Comment: I would recommend not the use `sizeToFit` at all. That's an old method that has been mostly replaced with other methods when we switched from autoresizing to autolayout about 6 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What are those other methods?

Comment: @linus_hologram `intrinsicContentSize` and setting hugging & compression resistance correctly. Your label already has the correct size thanks to its intrinsic size, you just need to give `postView` the correct constraints. And you already found the correct solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: Simply constraint the `postView`'s bottomAnchor to the labels bottomAnchor, like so:

```
postView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: postDescription.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

That's all the magic. Everything looks like it should :)

Answer (score 2):

Your view isn't sizing correctly because the view you return is just a normal `UIView` instance that has a subview in it. The default `sizeThatFits(_:)` implementation for `UIView` is just going to return `CGSize.zero`.

You have a couple options here:

1. Create a `PostView` class that subclasses `UIView`. You should add a `DefaultLabel` instance as a subview to this view similar to how you're doing so in `generatePostView(postItem:) -> UIView`. You should then implement `sizeThatFits(_:)` in `PostView` where it uses the `DefaultLabel`'s `sizeThatFits(_:)` value to calculate the correct size to return.
2. In your `generatePostView(postItem:) -> UIView` method, just return the `postDescription` instance instead of adding it to another `UIView` instance. I'm listing this as your second option because I'm guessing you have plans to add more subviews than just `postDescription` to the container view, so option 1 is easier to add more subviews to in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind providing a code example?

Comment: Hey, would you mind continuing the discussion in chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205355/subclassing-uiview-to-make-sizethatfits-do-something-useful

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution. I simply constrained the postViews bottom Anchor to the labels bottom Anchor.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation for `layoutSubviews`, it should never be invoked directly. Modifying this to the correct

```
/* postView.layoutSubviews() */

  postView.setNeedsLayout()
  postView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still not fixing the problem. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: easy way is to use stackView instead of UIView()

Comment: That wouldn't fix this broken behavior. It's bricking because it doesn't know which height it's subviews have.... how would Stack View help in that case? I still had to perform some kind of sizeToFit to make the StackView fit all of the subviews, right?

Comment: no ... there is no need to call sizetofit on stackview

Comment: Yes, it automatically arranges its subviews, but I want the subviews to have their own size and the stackview size accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205314/discussion-between-jawadali-and-linus-hologram).